# Encoding Path for Google Static Map API?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-static-api

I'm developing an app for iPhone and I want to generate a Google Static Map image with my polyline using the Google Static Map API V2 and an array of CLLocations I have. I'm using this piece of code right now:

```
NSArray *points = self.pathModel.pathPoints;
NSString *urlString = @"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?path=color:0x80008080%7Cweight:5%7C";
for (int i=0; i<points.count; i++) {
    float latitude = [(CLLocation *)points[i] coordinate].latitude;
    float longitude = [(CLLocation *)points[i] coordinate].longitude;
    if (i<points.count-1) {
        urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%f,%f%%7C", latitude, longitude];
    } else {
        urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%f,%f", latitude, longitude];
    }
}

urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&size=640x480&scale=2&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyDjU3Ly8X1TasKvUWgEF8v8uTE5PEU8ci8"];
```

The problem is that there's a limit on the number of points I can include in a URL format unless I provide an encoded path as described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm). **Is there any Objective-C API that encodes location points for Google Static Maps API? Or is there a way I can encode the urlString myself?**

I'm looking for an Objective-C type solution. I don't know C.

Answer (score 0):

Encoding and decoding of paths is now handled by the `google.maps.geometry.encoding` static methods `encodePath` and `decodePath`.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, but I'm looking for an Objective-C solution. I'm a new developer and I don't know C or Java.

Answer (score 0):

To **encode** a path in Objective-C, you can use the [`-encodedPath`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_path#a9b5b3808fbdc30e21a4b9d53e70058f7) method of [`GMSPath`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_path) in [Google Maps SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/):

```
GMSMutablePath* path = [GMSMutablePath path];
for(int i=0; i<points.count; i++)
{
    CLLocation* location = points[i];
    const CLLocationDegrees latitude = location.coordinate.latitude;
    const CLLocationDegrees longitude = location.coordinate.longitude;
    [path addLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];
}

NSString* encodedPath = [path encodedPath];
```

To **decode**, you can use the [`+pathFromEncodedPath:`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_path#a4060269354374332afbb532557c4899e) method of the same class.